# Как прочитать input.txt в обратном порядке строк

Tags: c++, файлы

файл input.txt

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
11 12
```

Мне надо его прочитать в обратно порядке строк.

```
11 12
9 10
7 8
5 6
3 4
1 2
```

Именно прочитать, потому как это упрощенная версия файла, в то время как настоящий будет очень большим, так что читать его несколько раз не желательно, как и записывать его целиком. Под прочитать я имею ввиду записать в переменную на время каждое число, также для идентификации знать текущую строчку. Я пробовал, но дальше указателя к файлу я не смог продвинутся

Comment: Поскольку строки разной длины, вариантов по сути два: каждый раз читать до нужного места, до некоторой N-ой строки, или прочесть один раз с запоминанием позиций начала всех строк, а потом переходить на нужное место в файле. А теперь изложите исходную задачу — может, для ее решения такие мучения и не нужны: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/195342

Comment: не могу, она олимпиадная. Но советом воспользуюсь, спасибо

Comment: Очень большой - это сколько в терабайтах?  Вы правда не можете прочитать его один раз, сохранив позиции всех концов строк? После того, как начала-концы строк известны,  можно прицельно читать построчно

Comment: Можно, наконец, просто читать и парсить с конца. Прочитали блок, обратным поиском находим конечные строки. выводим. Когда осталась последняя (по положению - первая) строка, читаем очередной блок, что перед ранее прочитанным, конкатенируем, и повторяем. Такой подход читает файл один раз, а не два, что должно быть быстрее, а также позволяет произвольно выбрать размер читаемого блока, исходя из установленного ограничения памяти. Правда, возможна проблема, если какая-либо строка превысит размер блока - эту ситуацию надо предусмотреть и, если встретится, обработать.

Comment: Ну, как знаете. Но вряд ли она звучит как "прочитать файл в обратном порядке строк"...

Comment: А потом выяснится, что "очень большой" - 10^5 строк, как на олимпиадах часто бывает ;)

Comment: ...и что надо просто написать новый файл, обратный данному  :) Кстати, утрачено великое искусство работы через диск. Помню, как DOS ковырялся, сортируя многомегабайтный файл — раскидывая его во временные файлы на диске... Кстати, этот вариант годится и для реверса большого файла, если задача именно в этом.

Comment: Сорян, действительно, файл не весит гигабайты и терабайты, он не больше 20 мб. Там есть рамки на время выполнения, так что потребность в производительном подходе есть. Я это понял после 60 неудачных попыток решить другую задачу на питоне.

Comment: 20 мб можно считать одним куском в память и забыть о проблемах. Или в вектор строк.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вариант с предварительным индексирование концов строк

```
#include <iostream> // std::cout
#include <fstream>  // std::ifstream
#include <vector>   // массив концов строк
#include <cstring>  // memchr
#include <chrono>   // отсечки времени
#include <string>   // для вывода буфера `char*`

// Читать мегабайт за раз
const size_t BUF_SIZE = 1024 * 1024;

const char *strnchr(const char *buf, char ch, size_t num)
{
    return static_cast<const char *>(memchr(buf, ch, num));
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<size_t> newlines{0};
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    size_t buf_start{0};

    std::ifstream is("/mnt/hdd/nikolay/some.txt", std::ifstream::binary); // 10Гб
    // std::ifstream is("some.txt", std::ifstream::binary); // 1 Гб
    // std::ifstream is("main.cpp", std::ifstream::binary); // маленький файл

    // Индексирование переводов строк
    is.seekg(0, is.beg);
    {
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        while (is)
        {
            auto len = is.readsome(buf, BUF_SIZE);
            if (len <= 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            auto end = buf + len;
            for (const char *ptr = strnchr(buf, '\n', end - buf); ptr != NULL; ptr = strnchr(ptr + 1, '\n', end - ptr))
            {
                newlines.push_back(buf_start + (ptr - buf));
            }
            buf_start += len;
        }
        auto elapsed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;

        long long milliseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
                                     elapsed)
                                     .count();
        std::cerr << "Время индексирования концов строк: " << milliseconds << "ms" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Число строк: " << newlines.size() << std::endl;
    }
    // Чтение строк
    {
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        is.seekg(0, is.end);
        size_t end = is.tellg();
        for (auto start = newlines.crbegin(); start != newlines.crend() && end > 0; start++)
        {
            is.seekg(*start);
            // Чтение строки. За раз читается не более 1 Мб
            for (size_t len = end - *start; len > 0;)
            {
                size_t size = (len < BUF_SIZE) ? len : BUF_SIZE;
                len -= size;
                is.readsome(buf, size);
                std::cout << std::string(buf, size);
            }
            end = *start;
        }
        auto elapsed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;

        long long milliseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
                                     elapsed)
                                     .count();
        std::cerr << "Время чтения и вывода строк в обратном порядке: " << milliseconds << "ms" << std::endl;
    }
    is.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы для 10Гб файла:

```
Время индексирования концов строк: 447ms
Число строк: 8388482
Время чтения и вывода строк в обратном порядке: 5383ms
```

Comment: завидую вашему RAID SSD, который 10гб файл может прочесть за 0,447сек (ведь чтобы проиндексировать все концы строк, надо как минимум каждый байт файла прочесть)

Comment: @Kromster завидовать стоит объему памяти в 128 Гб )) Линукс явно этот файл держит в кэше файловой системы в ОЗУ.

Comment: @Kromster сбросил кэш, файл выпихнул на HDD. Показания изменились: сканирование 11 секунд, вывод в обратном порядке 29 секунд

Comment: Честно, не припомню, чтобы существовали HDD (hard disk drive) способные выдавать скорости чтения в 1гб/сек. Как бы то ни было, мой комментарий был призват обратить внимание на то, что в ваших замерах не учтено (и не упомянуто) время требуемое для прочтения данных из файла в безграничную память. Надеюсь, что тот, кто увидит мой комментарий - обратит на это внимание и примет к сведению.